# Jest Testing with jsdom - Adding Google maps API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

Testing a React app that uses google maps autocomplete with the package react-geosuggest.

Setitng up js dom with this:

```
import requestAnimationFrame from './tempPolyfills';

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter(), disableLifecycleMethods: true });


const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM(`
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<our maps key>&libraries=places"></script>
      <script>console.log(Window.google)</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>`, {runScripts: "dangerously"});
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
    .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === 'undefined')
    .reduce((result, prop) => ({
      ...result,
      [prop]: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop),
    }), {});
  Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
copyProps(window, global);
```

I understand google maps API adds the google: method to window (so window.google}

However my tests are failing saying that the google maps API was not found on the page. I can confirm this trying to console log window.google is undefined.

Is this because jsdom is being returned before maps API can update the DOM?

Is there a better way of testing a component that uses a google maps API?

Tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958271/load-google-maps-api-in-jsdom) however that still gives me undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up mocking the entire google response and defining it in my setup tests file with:

`window.google = global.google = googleStub();`

if anyone cares

Comment: Hi @Dale King, could you give us more details how you did it?

Comment: The answer does not provide enough information on how to actually implement the mocks. What is the body of the function `googleStub()`?